# How To Complete Parsing JSON Array to List View in Android without Array Key

Tags: android, arrays, json, listview, parsing

First of all, i am a newbie in android.
Right now, I am building an application for school.
In one of it feature, there is a function to called what schedule for the student. I have learn tutorial for this function, but still it won't give me what I want. I want parsing value from JSONArray and then show values in ListView. But it give me only one accurate data only.

Let me start from JSON Array first

```
JSON Array

[{
"jam_start": "07:30:00",
"jam_end": "08:05:00",
"kegiatan": "Belajar (KBM)",
"mapel": "Seni Budaya Dan Keterampilan",
"nama_guru": "Vina Rosiyanti,S.Pd"
}, {
"jam_start": "08:06:00",
"jam_end": "08:40:00",
"kegiatan": "Belajar (KBM)",
"mapel": "Bahasa Indonesia",
"nama_guru": "Vina Rosiyanti,S.Pd"
}, {
"jam_start": "08:41:00",
"jam_end": "09:15:00",
"kegiatan": "Belajar (KBM)",
"mapel": "Bahasa Indonesia",
"nama_guru": "Vina Rosiyanti,S.Pd"
}, {
"jam_start": "11:01:00",
"jam_end": "11:35:00",
"kegiatan": "Belajar (KBM)",
"mapel": "Komputer",
"nama_guru": "Resi Gusta Arina,S.Pd.Gr"
}, {
"jam_start": "11:36:00",
"jam_end": "12:10:00",
"kegiatan": "Belajar (KBM)",
"mapel": "Komputer",
"nama_guru": "Resi Gusta Arina,S.Pd.Gr"
}, {
"jam_start": "13:01:00",
"jam_end": "13:35:00",
"kegiatan": "Belajar (KBM)",
"mapel": "Ilmu Pengetahuan Alam",
"nama_guru": "Vina Rosiyanti,S.Pd"
}, {
"jam_start": "13:36:00",
"jam_end": "14:10:00",
"kegiatan": "Belajar (KBM)",
"mapel": "Ilmu Pengetahuan Alam",
"nama_guru": "Vina Rosiyanti,S.Pd"
}]
```

And I will Start My Code

MainActivity.java

```
        String schedule = response.toString();
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(schedule);
        String jamMulai = null;
        String jamSelesai = null;
        String kegiatan = null;
        String mapel = null;
        String namaGuru = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject arrayELement = array.getJSONObject(i);
            mapel = arrayELement.getString("mapel");
            namaGuru = arrayELement.getString("nama_guru");
            kegiatan = arrayELement.getString("kegiatan");
            jamMulai = arrayELement.getString("jam_start");
            jamSelesai = arrayELement.getString("jam_end");

            HashMap<String, String> scheduleDetail = new HashMap<String, String>();
            scheduleDetail.put(mapel, mapel);
            scheduleDetail.put(namaGuru, namaGuru);
            scheduleDetail.put(kegiatan, kegiatan);
            scheduleDetail.put(jamMulai, jamMulai);
            scheduleDetail.put(jamSelesai, jamSelesai);

            scheduleListDetail.add(scheduleDetail);
            scheduleList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.scheduleList);

            ListAdapter listAdapter = new SimpleAdapter
                    (
                            Schedule.this, scheduleListDetail,
                            R.layout.schedulie_list, new String[]
                            {mapel, namaGuru, kegiatan, jamMulai, jamSelesai},
                            new int[]{R.id.txtNamaPelajaran, R.id.txtNamaGuru, R.id.txtKegiatan, R.id.txtJamMulai, R.id.txtJamSelesai}
                    );

            scheduleList.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        }
```

And this what I get
Wrong Result

[image]

And this what I want
Look for the last List View

[image]

So please help me, how to fix this
Thank you, and sorry if my english not so good

Best regards.

EDIT
This is My Object class

```
Schedule Object
public class ScheduleObject {

private String MataPelajaran;
private String NamaGuru;
private String Kegiatan;
private String JamMulai;
private String JamSelesai;

public String getMataPelajaran() {
    return MataPelajaran;
}

public void setMataPelajaran(String mataPelajaran) {
    MataPelajaran = mataPelajaran;
}

public String getNamaGuru() {
    return NamaGuru;
}

public void setNamaGuru(String namaGuru) {
    NamaGuru = namaGuru;
}

public String getKegiatan() {
    return Kegiatan;
}

public void setKegiatan(String kegiatan) {
    Kegiatan = kegiatan;
}

public String getJamMulai() {
    return JamMulai;
}

public void setJamMulai(String jamMulai) {
    JamMulai = jamMulai;
}

public String getJamSelesai() {
    return JamSelesai;
}

public void setJamSelesai(String jamSelesai) {
    JamSelesai = jamSelesai;
}

}
```

And this is my adapter class

```
enter code here
public class ScheduleAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ScheduleObject> {

private final Context context;
private ArrayList<ScheduleObject> scheduleObjects;

public ScheduleAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<ScheduleObject> scheduleObjects){
    super(context, textViewResourceId, scheduleObjects);
    this.context = context;
    this.scheduleObjects = new ArrayList<ScheduleObject>();
    this.scheduleObjects.addAll(scheduleObjects);
}

private class ViewHolder{
    TextView MataPelajaran;
    TextView NamaGuru;
    TextView Kegiatan;
    TextView JamMulai;
    TextView JamSelesai;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;

    if(convertView == null){

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.schedulie_list, null);

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.MataPelajaran = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtNamaPelajaran);
        viewHolder.NamaGuru = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtNamaGuru);
        viewHolder.Kegiatan = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtKegiatan);
        viewHolder.JamMulai = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtJamMulai);
        viewHolder.JamSelesai = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtJamSelesai);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }else{
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }

    ScheduleObject scheduleObject = scheduleObjects.get(position);
    viewHolder.MataPelajaran.setText(scheduleObject.getMataPelajaran());
    viewHolder.NamaGuru.setText(scheduleObject.getNamaGuru());
    viewHolder.Kegiatan.setText(scheduleObject.getKegiatan());
    viewHolder.JamMulai.setText(scheduleObject.getJamMulai());
    viewHolder.JamSelesai.setText(scheduleObject.getJamSelesai());

    return convertView;

}

}
```

Comment: move adapter out of the for loop

Comment: @Nilabja I have already move my adapter, but still won't work

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/
see this and let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set Adapter after for loop exicution like below

```
ArrayList<ScheduleObject> allscheduleObjects=new ArrayList<ScheduleObject>();
 for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject arrayELement = array.getJSONObject(i);
        ScheduleObject sche_object=new ScheduleObject ();


        sche_object.setMataPelajaran(arrayELement.getString("mapel"));
        sche_object.setNamaGuru(arrayELement.getString("nama_guru"));
        sche_object.setKegiatan(arrayELement.getString("kegiatan"));
        sche_object.setJamMulai(arrayELement.getString("jam_start"));
        sche_object.setJamSelesai(arrayELement.getString("jam_end"));

        allscheduleObjects.add(sche_object);


    }
 scheduleList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.scheduleList);

        ListAdapter listAdapter = new ScheduleAdapter
                (
                        Schedule.this,
                        R.layout.schedulie_list,allscheduleObjects
                );

        scheduleList.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: I'm sorry, it won't work. still doesn't give me what i want.

Comment: i have already post my edit question, and there are my object and adapter class

Comment: @BroJay..i ahve set all data according to you adapter and getter setter class..i think it will work now.

Comment: I am very sory for my late reply, now I will try, and thankyou very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

In android studio add this dependency in build.gradle of your app

```
 compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.4.1.2'
 compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.4.1.1'
 compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.4.1'
```

you will also need a POJO for this which will look like this

```
public class SchoolDTO{
private String jam_start;
private String jam_end;
private String kegiatan;
private String maple;
private String nama_guru;


...

your getter setter method

....

}
```

then when you try to convert string json to list just do this

```
ArrayList<SchoolDTO> schoolDTOs = new ObjectMapper.readValue(response.toString(), new TypeReference<List<SchoolDTO>>(){});
```

then pass the list to your listView this will save a lot of line of code

Comment: Could cut down on those dependencies and just use Gson

Comment: I am sorry for my late reply, thank you for your help, I will try it, and I will let you know